# IPv6 network on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: networking, server, netplan, ipv6

Can't seem to get the IPv6 network to work.

Unfortunately, I decided to reinstall the system anyway. And IPv6 doesn't work for me either.

Given: Dedicated IPv4 like: 45.80.XX.XX/32 and gateway 10.0.0.1;
IPv6 subnet: 2a03:XX:XX::5b8/125 (/125 prefix) and gateway 2a03:XX:XX::5b9

Bottom line: IPv4 works fine, **but IPv6 doesn’t want to do anything**...

**Question**: Tell me, please, a **possible solution to the problem with IPv6**.

My config is in /etc/netplan/00-network-all.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 45.80.XX.XX/32
        - 2a03:XX:XX::5b8/125
      nameservers:
       addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 2606:4700:4700::1111
        - 2001:4860:4860::8888
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0 # default
          via: 10.0.0.1 # Gateway IPv4
          metric: 100
          on-link: true
        - to: ::/0 # default
          via: 2a03:XX:XX::5b9 # Gateaway IPv6
          metric: 200
          on-link: true
```

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s3
    inet 45.80.XX.XX/32 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a03:XX:XX::5b8/125 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::XX:XX:XX:1904/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip -6 r

```
ip -6 r
Code:
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a03:XX:XX::5b8/125 dev ens3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via 2a03:XX:XX::5b9 dev ens3 proto static metric 200 onlink pref medium
```

ip neigh

```
10.0.0.1 dev ens3 lladdr 02:00:00:00:00:01 REACHABLE
2a03:XX:XX::5b9 dev ens3  FAILED
```

route -6

```
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
ip6-localhost/128              [::]                       U    256 2     0 lo
myhost/125                     [::]                       U    256 1     0 ens3
fe80::/64                      [::]                       U    256 1     0 ens3
[::]/0                         _gateway                   UGH  200 1     0 ens3
ip6-localhost/128              [::]                       Un   0   5     0 lo
myhost/128                     [::]                       Un   0   2     0 ens3
myhost/128                     [::]                       Un   0   2     0 ens3
ip6-mcastprefix/8              [::]                       U    256 4     0 ens3
[::]/0                         [::]                       !n   -1  1     0 lo
```

P.S. In IPv6 routing table there is a strange "UGH" flag, **maybe it should be just "UG" ???**

Answer (score 0):

You have a misconfiguration here, in that you are declaring two host addresses on the interface and one of them is the network address.  Your ipv6 config should be:

```
addresses:
  - 2a03:XX:XX::5ba/125
routes:
  - to: ::/0 # default
    via: 2a03:XX:XX::5b9
```

Comment: Yes, I experimented and forgot to restore the previous configuration.

But, the situation has not changed in any way IPv6 still does not work ...

Comment: I think the problem is that the Link-Local address has disappeared. But, **how to restore it ???**

Comment: can you post the ip -6 r and ip neigh output from the affected system after correcting the netplan config and running `netplan apply`?  I don't see anything in the netplan config that would break link-local addresses, so this may be configured elsewhere on the system and conflicting with the expected behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, I reinstalled the system and updated the header. P.S. I am usually use `sudo netplan try`... P.P.S. **Very need help with IPv6!**

Comment: so, I see your update to the contents of the question and it still shows you using 5b*8*, which is the network address, as the host address; instead of 5b*a*.  and you should avoid using `on-link: true` here which is unnecessary and is potentially obfuscating things in the output.